# Where is the error in my reasoning about this first-order linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Considering this first-order linear differential equation:

$\frac{dy}{dx} + 2y = 0$

Although I now know the correct general solution to be $y = c_1e^{-2x}$, I cannot figure out where I am going wrong with this apparently fallacious reasoning:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + 2y = 0$$
$$\int \frac{dy}{dx} dx  = \int -2y \text{ } dx$$
$$y = -2xy + c_1$$
$$y(2x+1) = c_1$$
$$y = \frac{c_1}{(2x+1)}$$

Comment: $\int ydx \ne xy + C$.

Comment: I thought the error had to be in this step, but I wonder why wolframalpha returns "True" for this input:
"integral of (-2y) dx == -2xy"
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28-2y%29+dx+%3D%3D+-2xy

Comment: WA must consider $y$ as a constant, and then indeed, $\int cdx=cx+c'$ for every constant $c$, say $c=-2y$.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way to solve would be
$$
\frac {dy}{dx} + 2y = 0 \implies \frac {dy}y = -2dx \implies \int \frac {dy}y = -2\int dx \implies \ln y = -2x + C_1 \implies \\
y = e^{C_1} e^{-2x} = Ce^{-2x}
$$

Comment: The OP does not ask for this, do they? Your comment, on the contrary, is quite on the spot.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing here is to separate the variables such that $y$ and $dy$ are on the LHS whilst $dx$ is on the RHS as given below:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= -2y$$

$$ \frac{1}{y}dy = -2 \ dx$$

Integrating both sides (C is a constant):

$$ \ln y = -2x + C$$

$$ y = Ae^{-2x}$$
 where $A = e^c$

You can read more about separation of variables [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables).